Is $E[Y|\mathcal{F}_T]=M_T$ if T is a stopping-time but not bounded?
Assume you have a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathcal{F}_n,P)$. Let $Y \in L^1(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. It can then be shown that $M_n=E[Y|\mathcal{F}_n]$ is an uniformly integrable martingale.
I am wondering if it holds that $M_T=E[Y|\mathcal{F}_T]$ if $T$ is a stopping-time not necessarily bounded? I am able to prove it for the bounded case.
If it holds in the general case. Do you see how to extend my proof below?
Proof bounded case:
By the Optional Sampling theorem(this theorem requires bounded stopping times) we have that $E[M_n|\mathcal{F}_{n\wedge T}]=M_{n\wedge T}$. But we also have $E[M_n|\mathcal{F}_{n\wedge T}]=E[E[Y|\mathcal{F}_n]|\mathcal{F}_{n\wedge T}]=E[Y|\mathcal{F}_{n\wedge T}]$. Hence we have a.s. that $M_{n\wedge T}=E[Y|\mathcal{F}_{n\wedge T}].$
We have by a.s. convergence that
$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}M_{n\wedge T}=M_T.$$
Now we must look at $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}E[Y|\mathcal{F}_{n\wedge T}]$.
Assume that $T$ is bounded by $c$. Then if $n\ge c$, we have that $n\wedge T=T$. Hence we get $n\wedge T \le T$, and $T\le n \wedge T$ for $n\ge c$. This means that for $n \ge c$ we have $\mathcal{F}_{T\wedge n}=\mathcal{F}_T$. Hence $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}E[Y|\mathcal{F}_{n\wedge T}]=E[Y|\mathcal{F}_T]$.
Hence we have
$M_T=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}M_{n\wedge T}=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}E[Y|\mathcal{F}_{n\wedge T}]=E[Y|\mathcal{F}_T]$.

1. The random variable $M_T$ is $\mathcal F_T$ measurable. Indeed, for each $n$,
$$
\{M_T\in B\}\cap\{T=n\}=\{M_n\in B, T=n\}\in\mathcal F_n.
$$
This holds even for $n=\infty$ when $T$ is allowed to take the value $\infty$, with $\mathcal F_\infty:=\sigma(\cup_n\mathcal F_n)$ and $M_\infty:=E[Y\mid\mathcal F_\infty]$.
2. $M_T$ is integrable.
3. If $A$ is an event in $\mathcal F_T$, then
$$
\eqalign{
E[M_T;A]
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty E[M_T ; A\cap\{T=n\}]\cr
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty E[M_n; A\cap\{T=n\}]\cr
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty E[E[Y\mid\mathcal F_n]; A\cap\{T=n\}]\cr
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty E[Y; A\cap\{T=n\}]\cr
&=E[Y; A].
}
$$
(The two uses of Fubini's theorem are easy to justify.)
4. This shows that the r.v. $M_T$ has all the properties required of $E[Y\mid\mathcal F_T]$; by uniqueness, $M_T=E[Y\mid\mathcal F_T]$ a.s.

Could you please show how you would show that $M_T$ is integrable? I am able to show it like this $E[|M_T|]=E[\liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}|M_{n\wedge T}|]$$\le \liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}E[|M_{n\wedge T}|] $$=\liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}E[|E[Y|\mathcal{F}{T \wedge n}|]\le\liminf\limits{n \rightarrow \infty}E[E[|Y||\mathcal{F}{T \wedge n}]=E[|Y|]$. But here I used that $M{T\wedge n}=E[Y|\mathcal{F}_{n\wedge T}]$, but to show this I used the Optional sampling theorem(I did this in the original post). Do you have a simpler way of showing integrability of $M_T$?

You have $|M_n|=|E[Y\mid\mathcal F_n]|\le E[|Y|\mid\mathcal F_n]$, so
$$
\eqalign{E[|M_T|]
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty E[|M_n|; T=n]
\le\sum_{n=0}^\infty E[E[|Y|\mid\mathcal F_n]; T=n]\cr
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty E[|Y|; T=n]
=E[|Y|]<\infty.\cr
}
$$
Here the two exchanges of summation and integration is valid because of Tonelli's theorem.

Thank you very much!
